# Story on a website in a journal entry/case study format, written in the perspective of a scientist observing an alien creature

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

The website has many different "cases". This one is about a creature or alien that a group of scientists are observing. It's written in the perspective of one single scientist that is picking the investigation up after another scientist quit (something like that, I'm not entirely sure). The scientists observe the creature's mood changes, feeding habits, etc. The scientist figures out that the creature likes chicken iirc, and in the end, the creature feels more at home. The ending is very wholesome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It sounds like you read this online; is that correct? Also, in roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I read this online this year, but I think it was written earlier than that. It might have been popular on Tumblr. I found it because someone mentioned it on Twitter.

Answer (score 5):

Reddit user Toast-Goat found it! It's [SCP-5031](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-5031)

> **Test 1:** Two stations activated. Screen 1 displayed the image of a rock. Its button dispensed rocks. Screen 2 displayed the image of a
> rotisserie chicken. Its button dispensed pieces of chicken.
>
> **Result:** SCP-5031 poked at the image of a chicken for a few minutes and eventually hit the button. Chicken was dispensed until SCP-5031
> was satisfied.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.